# How to implement the Lightweight http server using IIS

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to create a simple http server that only returns a text but I need to use IIS with.
Example, a person access a link to my server(http://anyUrl/abcdef) and my server returns a new url, like a url shorter. So it must be very fast.
I dont want to create a webforms project or MVC, so how can I do that?

Comment: This seems like you are going to duplicate what already exists.

Comment: @Ramhound What you mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the most lightweight way of accomplishing that would be to create an ASP.NET HTTP handler.  There is a short tutorial at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001

Answer (score 3):

You need a custom HttpHandler, this kind of thing is well documented, e.g.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could create an empty ASP.Net Application Project and add a Generic Handler (.ashx).

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("your stuff");
    }
```